# Frecuencia de cada uno de los elementos de un vector de n elementos

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buen día a todos,

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio sobre Arrays
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

según entiendo, debo crear 3 Arrays. El principal que es donde están los elementos, un segundo que almacene los elementos del principal, pero sin repetir los elementos y el tercero que contabilice la frecuencia.

Estuve intentando y lo que ve en el código es lo que he hecho. Sé que tiene varios errores aún, pero les agradecería si me pueden hacer observaciones e indicar si se puede hacer de manera más eficiente, o si en realidad hay que rehacerlo
`using System;

namespace UsoDeArrays
{
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
int[] vector; int[] vectorComparador; int[] frecuencia;
int tamaño, comparar;

```
        Console.WriteLine("Digite la cantidad de datos a ingresar (Tamaño del vector)");
        tamaño = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        vector = new int[tamaño]; 
        vectorComparador = new int[tamaño];
        frecuencia = new int[tamaño]; 
        

        for (int i = 0; i< vector.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el numero para el elemento {0}: ", (i+1)); 
            vector[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            vectorComparador[i] = vector[i];
        }

        
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.Length; i++)
        {
            frecuencia[i] = 1; 
            for (int j = 0; j < vector.Length; j++)
            {
                if (vector[i] == vectorComparador[j++])
                    frecuencia[i]++;
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < vector.Length;k++)
        {
            if (vector[k] == vectorComparador[k++])
            Console.WriteLine("La frecuencia del numero {0} es {1}", vector[k], frecuencia[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

}
`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta es una solución posible utilizando un solo bucle for.

La clave está en ordenar el vector con Array.Sort() para luego recorrerlo.
Para obtener el resultado en orden descendente descomentar la línea que sigue al Array.Sort()

Yo utilice los valores en duro del problema pero si gustas le puedes agregar al inicio un bucle for para hacer la carga de los valores del vector "vectorOriginal", asi como tu lo hiciste funcionaria bien.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] vectorOriginal = new int[] { 6, 7, 5, 4, 5, 3, 6, 7, 2, 6 };
            int[] vectorUnicos = new int[vectorOriginal.Length];
            int[] vectorFrecuencia = new int[vectorOriginal.Length];

            Array.Sort(vectorOriginal);
            //Array.Reverse(vectorOriginal); //si quieres hacer orden descendente descomentar esta linea

            int index = 0;
            int lastValue = vectorOriginal[index];
            vectorUnicos[index] = lastValue;
            vectorFrecuencia[index]++;

            for (int i = index + 1; i < vectorOriginal.Length; i++)
            {
                if (vectorOriginal[i] == lastValue)
                {
                    vectorFrecuencia[index]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    index++;
                    lastValue = vectorOriginal[i];
                    vectorUnicos[index] = lastValue;
                    vectorFrecuencia[index]++;
                }
            }

            PrintVector(vectorOriginal);
            Console.WriteLine(" :vector original");
            PrintVector(vectorUnicos);
            Console.WriteLine(" :vector unicos");
            PrintVector(vectorFrecuencia);
            Console.WriteLine(" :vector frecuencias");

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static void PrintVector(int[] vector)
        {
            Console.Write("|");
            Array.ForEach(vector, x => Console.Write($"{x}|"));
        }
```

El resultado obtenido:

```
PS D:\Documents\Projects\testSOF> dotnet run
|2|3|4|5|5|6|6|6|7|7| :vector original   
|2|3|4|5|6|7|0|0|0|0| :vector unicos     
|1|1|1|2|3|2|0|0|0|0| :vector frecuencias
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por la respuesta, funciona super bien xD, en serio muchas gracias. Hay un par de cosas que no comprendo sobre tu código ¿hay alguna manera de contactar para que me saques de duda?

Comment: @EduardoLopezRodriguez si podes preguntarme por aca sobre las dudas o en mi perfil esta mi github con mi correo

Comment: Te envié correo,  espero no sea molestia